# The fundamental theorem of calculus: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^x f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t = f(x)$ and nothing more

Tags: calculus, notation

My textbook writes, just as wikipedia, but I'd like to write it shorter.

Can the fundamental theorem of calculus
 be written as
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^x f(t)\: \mathrm{d}t = f(x)$$

Comment: To what most mathematicians are concerned, it can. Why do you think it could not be so?

Comment: You are right, symbolically, what you've written is good enough for the fundamental theorem of calculus. But mathematicians want to be more precise about what $f(t)$, etc., and furthermore, it's only half of the theorem. The other part states $\int_a^b F'(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$.

Comment: I think that many mathematicians might want to say "For an integrable function $f$, and any point $x$ at which $f$ is continuous, [your formula here]." Otherwise what you've written is false in general.

Comment: @nayrb no, it's the corollary.

Comment: The above comments are true statements, but the OP seems to be worried about notation here and not about the hypothesis and such.

Comment: It isn't as cute but I'd write $\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( x\mapsto \int_a^x f(t)\: \mathrm{d}t\right)\right)(u) = f(u)$ which can be simplified to $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( x\mapsto \int_a^x f(t)\: \mathrm{d}t\right) = f$ if you want to say that for all $u$.

Comment: @xavierm02 That is the reason why I said 'most mathematicians'. I prefer the notation you suggest as well, or better yet $\left( x\mapsto \int_a^x f\right)' = f$.

Comment: @Jacob. No, that's not enough. Symbols without the relevant assumptions are meaningless. If you just write that, the rest is false. If you write that, and in addition specify that $f$ is, say, continuous, then it is fine.

Comment: If you preface your equation with the following, then everything is okay: "If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and is continuous at some $x \in (a,b)$, then"

Comment: Question to close?